# Openshift Container Platform V3.X vs. Fabric8

Tags: containers, openshift, kubernetes, microservices, fabric8

I took a look at Fabric8 Microservices Platform and searched for some alternatives for comprehension. I found Red Hats Openshift Container Platform, which seems to be the same as Fabric8, but not Open-Source. 
I tried to figure out what are the major benefits of Red Hats solution.
I am already on the Openstack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabric8 is a tool that helps you building cloud ready applications whereas Openshift will help you deploying and managing those applications.
You can deploy Fabric8 locally on the cloud or on Openshift.

[Fabric8](https://fabric8.io/) is Open-Source and the correspondent supported product is [Openshift.io](https://openshift.io/)
[Openshift Origin](https://www.openshift.org/) is the Open-Source product, and [Openshift Container Platform](https://www.openshift.com/) is the supported product.

Hope that helps